# Fluent Validation Compare Field String format args

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, server-side, fluent, fluentvalidation

I have 2 properties Email and Confirm Email. How to provide string format arg for both localized property Name
For Example:-

```
public class Account 
{
  public string Email {get;set;}
  public string ConfirmEmail {get;set;}
}

Public AccountValidator : AbstractValidator<Account>
{
   public AccountValidator()
   {
      RuleFor(a=> a.Email)
                  .Equal(a=>a.ConfirmEmail)
                  .WithLocalizedMessage(() => MyResource.compareFields);
    }  
}
```

My resource File has message like this:-

**'{PropertyName}' and '{ ??? }' fields do not match.**

What should I use in ??? so that it says : -

**'Email' and 'ConfirmEmail' fields do not match.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this to define a custom parameter in your message: `{0}`. So your the message would look like this in your resource file.

```
'{PropertyName}' and '{0}' fields do not match.
```

And pass in the `"ConfirmEmail"` as an extra argument to the `WithLocalizedMessage` call:

```
RuleFor(a => a.Email)
    .Equal(a => a.ConfirmEmail)
    .WithLocalizedMessage(() => MyResource.compareFields, "ConfirmEmail");
```